# Displaying pdf file in cgi with python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

The following code works fine to display a pdf file with python 3.2. However with python 3.6 it doesn't (the browser gives a 'Failed to load PDF document' error). I think this is because the byte string returned by `read()` in 3.6 prints with a leading `b'` and trailing `'`.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in 3.6? Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open('sol.pdf', 'rb') as fp:
    print("Content-type: application/pdf\n")
    print(fp.read())
```

Comment: `sys.stdout.buffer.write(fp.read())` (Source: [Python 3: Write to stdout in binary mode](https://wizardsofdos.de/blog/2014/02/python-3-write-to-stdout-in-binary-mode/))

Comment: Actually, that might not work. Are you using `http.server`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try that and it didn't work, though I'm not quite sure why: I get an internal server error, but if I run it in a console it appears to run fine and produces a stream of junk which looks the same as that produced by the working python 3.2 version. I'm not using `http.server`. (I'm new to this, and don't know the optimal techniques.)

Comment: What web server framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
with open('sol.pdf', 'rb') as fp:
    print("Content-type: application/pdf\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(fp.read())
```

The sys.stdout.flush needs to appear before the sys.stdout.buffer.write to ensure that the headers appear first.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works. As additional tip, If instead of displaying the pdf you want to propose the file for download, then replace `print("Content-type: application/pdf\n")` by `print("Content-Disposition: attachment\n")`.